# Want to add the UIActivityIndicator beside the UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can i add the activity indicator beside the right bar button item (CreateNew button)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One of the approaches that you can use is initializing the Bar Button using some custom view.

A bar minimum code which can help you get some hint is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIView* aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 40)];
    [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[aView layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [[aView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    UIActivityIndicatorView* loadView  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [loadView startAnimating];
    [aView addSubview:loadView];
    [loadView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30)];
    [loadView release];

    UIButton* aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 80, 35)];
    [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aView addSubview:aButton];
    [aButton release];


    UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aView];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];
    [aView release];
    [barButton release];

}
```

This is If you do it programmatically , else you can also make use of nib. Creating bar button this way  will look something like this -

[image]

You can look for more option making using of `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aView];` method.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

For this try to customize `UINavigationController` Class.

Add Activity Indicator on **navigationBar** and control it from your `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the activity indicator using the following code:

```
    //Create an instance of activity indicator view
    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];

    //set the initial property
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator hidesWhenStopped];

    //Create an instance of Bar button item with custome view which is of activity indicator
    UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
    //Set the bar button the navigation bar
    [self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

    //Memory clean up
    [activityIndicator release];
    [barButton release];
```

Please refer this [link](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/add-uiactivityindicatorview-to-uinavigationbar.php) for detailed code.